# Exim (or postfix) different smarthost / authentication based on originating ip address

Tags: postfix, exim

Is it possible use with Exim (or postfix) use different smarthost / user authentication based on originating ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Exim allows any configuration at all. Refer to the chapters [33](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-smtp_authentication.html) and [43](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Exim allows override/modification the configuration in ACLs.  You could use a connection ACL to select the configuration you want based on IP address.

The configuration mechanism has extensive conditional capabilities.

There are a variety of methods you can you to achieve your goals.

- Set a variable for the smartrouter.
- Muliple smartrouter configurations activated based on IP or variable.

It is possible to have multiple authenticators in the configuration.

- Set the authenticor ACL based on the IP address.
- Set a variable to specify the password file.
- Conditionally advertise authenticators based on a condition.

It is possible to conditionally include configuration file.  This enables you a wide latitude in configuration.

Read the [Exim Specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/index.html) to get an idea of the capabilities.  There is also a [FAQ](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/FAQ).  There are several router FAQ entries which could applied to your requirement.